# How to make a toggle button inside a for loop to activate on only the clicked element

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this button that upon clicking should reveal only the input field for the delected list item. However it reveals all the input fields for all list items.

I could use css `visibility` property but that only hides the input but does not remove it from the DOM hence leaving an awkward space when hidden

Comment: Show related code. If you have space problem then you can go to display:none.

Comment: use `ngif` then it would remove in the DOM. Show your code that problem would be found it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try css `display: none;` to remove the white space